# Cartoon with an amusement park on the moon

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I have a vague memory of a cartoon Sci Fi series in the late 1990's which featured an amusement park on the moon, with blackjack, and hookers.

Comment: Well, if it helps, the [second episode of Futurama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Series_Has_Landed) had them visit the moon... and it was basically a crappy carnival type amusement park.  I don't remember blackjack and hookers per se, but it wouldn't surprise me..

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e35AQK014tI

Comment: Too easy to google. This question deserves a negative vote.

Comment: @Ginasius I genuinely wish you the best in all of your future endeavours.

Comment: So do I to you, specially in the constructive questions you may ask to this community. :)

Comment: As a user who decided to downvote your question, I must say that it's too trivial to ask, because you could have googled "blackjack hookers cartoon" and got your answer. The fact that you had to ask shows that you have done no such thing, and such laziness is not something I personally think is acceptable for this site.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is *Futurama*; Season 1 Episode 2 - [**The Series has Landed**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Series_Has_Landed) (1999)

> Settling into their new jobs, Fry, Leela, and Bender are introduced to the other Planet Express employees: Doctor John A. Zoidberg, intern Amy Wong, and bureaucrat Hermes Conrad. It becomes apparent that the ship needs a captain, and Leela is chosen. **On their first mission, a delivery to the Moon, Fry undergoes severe culture shock. No longer a daring voyage of exploration, lunar travel has become a day trip to an amusement park called Luna Park. By the 31st century, the actual details of Project Apollo are lost and have been replaced by musicals about whalers on the moon and goofy gophers. This upsets Fry, who wants to see the real moon.**

Comment: Bonus **"[Whalers on the moon"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4PWnsamvE2k)** remix